# Convert an observable to an array or modify functions working with observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I use the following code to calculate the average of the attempts of all successfully completed experiments from the specified array. The code works for the specified array. The problem is now that the interface does not provide an array but an observable. The structure of the observable I add below. What can I do now?

Can I convert the observable to an array or can I change my function without much effort so that it also works for observables?

The Code:

```js
const cResult = [{
  name: 'Barbara',
  results: [
    {
      experiment: 'experiment 1',
      attempts: 5,
      successful: false
    },
    {
      experiment: 'experiment 2',
      attempts: 7,
      successful: true
    }   
  ]
},
{
  name: 'Bob',
  results: [
    {
      rxperiment: 'experiment 1',
      attempts: 3,
      successful: true
    },
    {
      experiment: 'experiment 2',
      attempts: 4,
      successful: true
    }   
  ]
}]
            
            const resultsObj = cResult.reduce((acc, cResults) => {
            cResults.results.forEach(t => {
              if (t.successful) {
                if (acc[t.experiment] == null) acc[t.experiment] = []
                acc[t.experiment].push(t.attempts)
              }
            })
            return acc;
          }, {});
          Object.keys(resultsObj).map(key => {
            const count = resultsObj[key].length
            const sum = resultsObj[key].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
            avg = sum / count
            console.log(avg)
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

The structure of the given observable:

```
resultSet {
  name: User;
  results: {
    experiment: Task
    attempts: number
    successful: boolean
  }[];
}
```

Comment: You can use the `toArray` operator to turn an Observable into an Array. Consider though that it requires that the Observable completes, which is by the way mandatory if you want to calculate an average I guess.

Comment: I tried the following:

..const resultsObj = resultObservable.toArray().reduce((acc, cResults) => {..

but it gives an Error: TS2339: Property 'toArray' does not exist on type 'Observable '.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you subscribe to the observable? What's the `next` value of it? Isn't it the array you are looking for?

Comment: there is no observable at all inside your code snippet. Can you pelase add more details? What is your function? Where is the observable you want to convert into an array?

Comment: `toArray` is an operator which has to be used within a `pipe`. It is not a method of Observable. I suggest you take a look at how Observables work to make sure you have the right understanding of their mechanics, which are slightly different from the usual stuff, but very powerful when understood.